# Asmack file transfer progress always at 0.0

Tags: android, xmpp, file-transfer, openfire, asmack

Hi there i am using asmack-android-19-0.8.10.jar and openfire to develop file transfer. i refered to [harryjoy.me](http://harryjoy.com/2012/08/18/file-transfer-in-android-with-asmack-and-openfire/#comments) but i have problems when sending the file where transfer.getProgress() always return 0.0. below is the log file.

Send File :

```
05-06 15:42:35.669: D/SMACK(25533): 03:42:35 PM SENT (1103132248): 
<iq id="7dnrX-23" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" from="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set">
    <si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="jsi_8243824082816759940" mime-type="image/jpeg" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer">
        <file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="pic_1399362155598.jpg" size="94630" >
            <desc>lolo</desc>
        </file>
        <feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
            <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
                <field var="stream-method" type="list-single">
                    <option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option>
                    <option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></option>
                </field>
            </x>
        </feature>
    </si>
</iq>

05-06 15:42:35.719: D/SMACK(25533): 03:42:35 PM RCV  (1103132248): 
<iq id="7dnrX-23" to="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack" from="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="result">
    <si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si">
        <feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
            <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
                <field var="stream-method">
                    <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value>
                    <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value>
                </field>
            </x>
        </feature>
    </si>
</iq>

05-06 15:42:35.719: D/SMACK(25533): 03:42:35 PM SENT (1103132248): 
<iq id="7dnrX-24" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="get">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></query>
</iq>

05-06 15:42:40.713: D/SMACK(25533): 03:42:40 PM SENT (1103132248): 
<iq id="7dnrX-25" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set">
    <open xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" block-size="4096" sid="jsi_8243824082816759940" stanza="iq"/>
</iq>
05-06 15:42:40.744: D/SMACK(25533): 03:42:40 PM RCV  (1103132248): 
<iq id="7dnrX-25" to="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack" from="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="result"/>

05-06 15:42:40.754: D/SMACK(25533): 03:42:40 PM SENT (1103132248): 
<iq id="7dnrX-26" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set">
    <data xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" seq="0" sid="jsi_8243824082816759940">
        ** Some data **

05-06 15:42:45.758: D/SMACK(25533): 03:42:45 PM SENT (1103132248): 
<iq id="7dnrX-27" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set">
    <data xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" seq="0" sid="jsi_8243824082816759940">
        ** Some data **

05-06 15:42:50.763: D/SMACK(25533): 03:42:50 PM SENT (1103132248): 
<iq id="7dnrX-28" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set">
<close xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" sid="jsi_8243824082816759940"/></iq>
```

Receive file :

```
    05-06 04:53:06.409: D/SMACK(1324): 04:53:06 AM RCV  (1384483676): 
<iq id="0cxQ1-38" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" from="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set">
    <si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="jsi_4342883008583481067" mime-type="image/jpeg" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer">
        <file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="pic_1399351997548.jpg" size="93096"><desc>lolo</desc></file>
        <feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
            <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
                <field var="stream-method" type="list-single">
                    <option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option>
                    <option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></option>
                </field>
            </x>
        </feature>
    </si>
    </iq>
05-06 04:53:06.413: D/SMACK(1324): 04:53:06 AM SENT (1384483676): 
<iq id="0cxQ1-38" to="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack" from="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="result">
<si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si">
    <feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
        <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
            <field var="stream-method">
                <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value>
                <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value>
            </field>
        </x>
    </feature>
</si>
</iq>

05-06 04:53:06.429: D/SMACK(1324): 04:53:06 AM RCV  (1384483676): 
<iq id="0cxQ1-39" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="get" from="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
</iq>

05-06 04:53:11.433: D/SMACK(1324): 04:53:11 AM RCV  (1384483676): 
<iq id="0cxQ1-40" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set" from="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack">
    <open xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" block-size="4096" sid="jsi_4342883008583481067" stanza="iq"/>
</iq>

05-06 04:53:11.441: D/SMACK(1324): 04:53:11 AM SENT (1384483676): 
<iq id="0cxQ1-40" to="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack" from="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="result">
</iq>

05-06 04:53:11.485: D/SMACK(1324): 04:53:11 AM RCV  (1384483676): 
<iq id="0cxQ1-41" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set" from="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack">
<data xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" seq="0" sid="jsi_4342883008583481067">
** Some data **

05-06 04:53:16.545: D/SMACK(1324): 04:53:16 AM RCV  (1384483676): 
<iq id="0cxQ1-42" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set" from="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack">
<data xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" seq="0" sid="jsi_4342883008583481067">      ** Some data **

05-06 04:53:16.545: D/SMACK(1324): 04:53:16 AM RCV  (1384483676): 
** Some data **</data></iq>

05-06 04:53:21.501: D/SMACK(1324): 04:53:21 AM RCV  (1384483676): 
<iq id="0cxQ1-43" to="lala@kaoru-pc/Smack" type="set" from="lolo@kaoru-pc/Smack">
    <close xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" sid="jsi_4342883008583481067"/>
</iq>
```

This is the error code i got from transfer.getException for sendFile();

```
05-07 09:08:01.917: D/Error(12587): chatRoom.java at line 892 : error writing to output stream: 
05-07 09:08:01.917: D/Error(12587):   -- caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while closing stream: No response from server.
```

**** UPDATED ****

Sender.java

```
try {
                    FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(OpenFireAuthenticateService.connection);
                    FileTransferNegotiator.getInstanceFor(OpenFireAuthenticateService.connection);
                    FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(OpenFireAuthenticateService.connection,true);

                    // Create the outgoing file transfer
                    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(userName+"@"+OpenFireAuthenticateService.serverName + "/Smack");

                    // Send the file                
                    transfer.sendFile(new File(path), OpenFireAuthenticateService.hostName.substring(0, OpenFireAuthenticateService.hostName.indexOf("@")));

                    while(!transfer.isDone()) {

                        if(transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
                            Log.d("Error","chatRoom.java at line 879 : "+transfer.getError().toString());
                        } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)
                                            || transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.refused)) {
                               Log.d("Error","chatRoom.java at line 882 : "+transfer.getError().toString());
                        }
                        try {
                            Log.d("TEST", "STATUS: " + transfer.getStatus().toString() + " SIZE: " + new File(path).length() + " PROGRESS: " + transfer.getProgress() + " StreamID : "+transfer.getStreamID());
                            Thread.sleep(1000L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                               Log.d("Error","chatRoom.java at line 887 : "+e.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    if(transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.refused)) {
                        Log.d("Error","chatRoom.java at line 946 : "+transfer.getException());
                    }
                    else if(transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
                        Log.d("Error","chatRoom.java at line 949 : "+transfer.getException());
                    }
                    else if(transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)){
                        Log.d("Error","chatRoom.java at line 952 : "+transfer.getException());
                    } else {
                                Log.d("TEST","Success");
                    }

                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    Log.d("Error","chatRoom.java at line 895 : "+e.toString());
                }
```

Receiver.java

```
ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
                if (sdm == null){
                    sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
                }
                sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
                sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
                sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items");

                FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
                FileTransferNegotiator.getInstanceFor(connection);
                FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection,true);
                manager.addFileTransferListener(new ServiceFileTransferListener(context));
```

ServiceFileTransferListener.java

```
try {               
                File f = new File(filePath);
                IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();

                transfer.recieveFile(f);
                while(!transfer.isDone()) {
                       try{
                          Thread.sleep(1000);
                          Log.d("TEST", "STATUS: " + transfer.getStatus().toString() + " SIZE: " + f.length() + " Stream ID : " + transfer.getStreamID());
                       }catch (Exception e) {
                          Log.e("Error", "ServiceFileTransferListener.java at line 61 : "+e.getMessage());
                       }
                       if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
                          Log.e("Error ", "ServiceFileTransferListener.java at line 72 : "+ transfer.getStatus());
                       }
                       if(transfer.getException() != null) {
                          Log.e("Error","ServiceFileTransferListener.java at line 75 : "+transfer.getException().getStackTrace());
                       }
                }
                Log.d("TEST","Received : "+request.getFileName() + " from " +request.getRequestor() + " File Size : "+request.getFileSize());
                Log.d("TEST","Status : "+transfer.getStatus());
                groupChatName = request.getRequestor().substring(0, request.getRequestor().indexOf("@"));   
                msgHeader = request.getFileName().substring(0, 3);
                msgBody = request.getFileName();
                memberName = "from";

            } 
            catch(XMPPException e) {
                Log.d("Error","ServiceFileTransferListener.java at line 79 : "+ e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: have you solved your problem of file sending in xmpp, if yes please send me the dummy for sending file

Comment: @nitesh i solved the file sending problem by using back the older version of asmack (asmack-jre-buddycloud-2012-12-11.jar). Refer to my question above (harryjoy.com)

Comment: i got service unavailable 503 while debuging is this related to my server or not?

Comment: XML RESPONSE                                                  <error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>

Comment: check your connection to the server and please follow as the guide stated. Then should be no problem.

Comment: I have checked it many times please give me your email id i will forward my code to you then please check it

Answer (score 1):

Implementation looks buggy, e.g.

```
<feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
        <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
            <field var="stream-method">
                <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value>
                <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value>
            </field>
        </x>
    </feature>
```

is wrong reply, because XEP-0095 say:

> If acceptable the Receiver MUST select one of the presented stream
>   types to use.

Try to use only one stream method and/or submit bugreport to Smack.

Comment: Yea. I realize that but then sender will use IBB as stream types. Still it failed. Status always in progress and progress always 0.0. After that i got the exception shown above. any idea what caused it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Filled as [SMACK-561](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-561)

Comment: Have you got solution for the same ? where I have to write code ?

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for the detailed question. That makes it easy to get an idea what could be wrong. While [vitalyster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23519620/194894) is right, the stanza is a violation of the spec, I don't think this is the cause for the problem.

What looks wrong is that we don't see any result IQs for the set IQs that carry a data element, ie the stanza of [Example 7 in XEP-47](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html#send) is missing. That's all I can say with the provided information. I suggest you grab a debugger to find the root cause. <sup>Good that (a)Smack is open source</sup>

Edit: You call `SmackAndroid.init(Context)` as aSmacks README tells you to do, or not?

Comment: Yes. I've included SmackAndroid.init(getApplicationContext()) before creating connection. Also add IQProvider manually. What do you mean grab a debugger? ConnectionConfiguration..setDebuggerEnabled(true);? i included this as well

Comment: i tried use back the version of asmack-jre-buddycloud-2012-12-11.jar guess what it worked! how it is possible?

Comment: @Flow, of course, when both parties uses Smack, they can somehow transfer files without following specs :) But when another party uses different library, it *is* a root of problem. For example, I get "negotiation failed" error just after that stanza and that is why I have found specs violation. Not all libraries have detailed error reporting, and we can see lot of filetransfer-related Smack questions here on StackOverflow, when user can not send/receive file using Smack.

Comment: @vitalyster why is it an old asmack would work but not for the new version? i revert back to the old version but other features of my app crash due to the old library has some bug on other features.

Comment: @vitalyster It is correct that there are many file transfer related questions to Smack. I usually credit this due the complexity of XMPP file transfer and most people failing to understand it. But, of course, I'm happy about every report where Smack violates the spec.

Comment: @Kaoru My first guess would be that you have somehow no Provider active for 'data` elements with the `http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb' namespace. Could you verify that? And I meant with "grab a debugger" that you should approach the problem with a debugger.

Comment: @Flow 
pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
pm.addIQProvider("data", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());

Both are included in my IQProvider. I guess this is not the problem.

Comment: @Kaoru I suggest that you try to determine why those IQs are not acknowledged with the help of a debugger. You don't need to add the providers manually, aSmack does take care of this for you.

Comment: @Flow could you shred some light for me on how to use the debugger?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52266/discussion-between-kaoru-and-flow)

Comment: I would expect to find good debugging tutorials on the internet. You are welcome to join #smack (freenode) and idle around there.

Comment: @Flow i guess debugger you said is setDebuggerEnabled(true); and log shown on LogCat. But i only encountered with the error above shown. How should i proceed from there? and i realized the IBB transfer on asmack-jre-buddycloud-2012-12-11.jar is the same as current version. The only different is S5B success on older version.